# Multi language feature in Angular

Tags: angular

In my Angular application logging I need to setup multi language feature. In simple words in the login page there'll be a dropdown list with relevant languages and user can select one of those. Then in application that language is used. I would like to know the way of implementing this.

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/i18n.html

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer; Thanks!